# Как в php отобразить весь массив строк?

Tags: php, mysql

В MYSQL в поле genres содержатся несколько значений, например в записи в этом поле содержится action, sport, 3d. Важно: в этом поле могут содержаться как 3, так и 10 значений.

Вот таким образом я отделяю каждое значение от запятой:

```
$genres = $row["genres"];
$gnrs = explode(',', $genres);
```

Далее вывожу в html таким образом:

```
<li><?php echo $gnrs[0]; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $gnrs[1]; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $gnrs[2]; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $gnrs[3]; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $gnrs[4]; ?></li>
```

На выходе получаю:

```
<li>action</li>
<li>sport</li>
<li>3d</a></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

Вопрос: каким образом мне вывести только все значения? Чтобы получилось вот так:

```
<li>action</li>
<li>sport</li>
<li>3d</li>
```

Comment: Используй `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понял, что ты хочешь сделать, но массив можно вывести через foreach

```
<?foreach $gnrs as $gnr {  ?>
<li> <? echo $gnrl ?> <li>
<? } ?>
```

вот прям эту конструкцию можешь вставить

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php foreach ($gnrs as $gnr):  ?>
<li> <?= $gnr ?> </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```